# Centered image on video tag

Tags: javascript, html, css, video

Allright for a project I need to have a centered image (a play button) rendered at runtime on top off a video depending on the UserAgent. If the userAgent isn't Firefox I want to display the image since Firefox has it's own playEvent and button on top of the video at start. All my previous attempts to do so have failed.

I tried:

- tag in the video tag and put the z-index to 10 while putting video z-index to 1
- Putting a div with a background image around the video tag

Are there any other ways to do this, and please don't reply use a poster since I allready have a poster I need to use.

-EDIT-

Code:

```
<tr>
    <td runat="server" width="680px" height="383px" id="vContainer">
        <video id="player" style="z-index: 1" width="100%" height="100%" title="" controls runat="server">
            <source runat="server" id="ffVideo" type="video/ogg" />
            <source runat="server" id="mp4Video" type="video/mp4" />
        </video>
        <embed id="playerOld" width="680px" autostart="false" allowfullscreen="true" height="383px" title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4" runat="server" />
    </td>
</tr>
```

Comment: Share your attempts. A simple layer with propper z-index will work.

Comment: It should and I can find the <img> in the rendered html it's jsut behind the video.

Comment: There is not an `<img>` tag in nowhere...

Comment: I deleted it out of pure frustration

Comment: I answer you, I post a fiddle that's working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As simple as put a tag and give it more z-index. You can make it running: http://jsfiddle.net/65rda3jq/

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="img"></div>
     <video id="player" style="z-index: 1" width="100%" height="100%" title="" controls
        runat="server">
        <source runat="server" id="ffVideo" type="video/ogg" />
        <source runat="server" id="mp4Video" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <embed id="playerOld" width="680px" autostart="false" allowfullscreen="true" height="383px"
        title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4" runat="server" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
.cont {
    position:relative;
}

video { position: relative; }
.img {z-index:10; background: #f00; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; width: 50px; height: 50px; }
```

Answer (score 1):

> Try this one:

## html:

```
<div class="cont">
    <div class="img"><span class='play_icon'></span></div>
     <video id="player" style="z-index: 1" width="100%" height="100%" title="" controls
        runat="server">
        <source runat="server" id="ffVideo" type="video/ogg" />
        <source runat="server" id="mp4Video" type="video/mp4" />
      </video>
      <embed id="playerOld" width="680px" autostart="false" allowfullscreen="true" height="383px"
        title="" style="display: none" type="application/mp4" runat="server" />
</div>
```

## CSS:

```
.cont {
    position:relative;
    background:rgba(42,42,42,0.9);
    border:none;
    color:#fff;
    outline: none;
}
.play_icon{
    width: 0; 
    height: 0; 
    border-top: 20px solid transparent;
    border-bottom: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 36px solid #fc8b02;
    margin: auto;  
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}

video { position: relative; }
.img {
  margin: auto;  
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    width: 10%;
    height: 16%;
    cursor: pointer;
    border-radius: 5px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/Grald/kgwvupjm/